# angularjs - ui-router route from child state to another child state that has own controller

Tags: angularjs, forms, routes, angular-ui-router, state

I'm facing a problem here with ui-router, Is the first time that I use it, and even with the docs I got a little messy.. The problem is that I have my app states like this with custom controllers:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

        // App routing
        .state('form', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'formBase.html',
            controller: 'formController',
        })

        .state('form.profile', {
            url: '/profile',
            templateUrl: 'modules/about/about.view.html'
        })

        .state('form.movie', {
            url: '/movie',
            templateUrl: 'modules/movie/movie.view.html',
            controller: 'MovieController as vm'
        })

        .state('form.series', {
            url: '/series',
            templateUrl: 'modules/series/series.view.html',
            controller: 'SeriesController as vm'
        });

    // catch all route
    // send users to the form page
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('//profile');
})
```

But when I'm on a state like /profile (form.profile), and click a button in the template with **ui-sref="form.movie"** for example I can't go to state /movie, I got an error:

```
    Error: Could not resolve 'form.movie' from state 'form.profile'
at Object.v.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)
    at Object.v.go (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)
    at angular-ui-router.min.js:7
    at angular.js:18953
    at e (angular.js:5824)
    at angular.js:6100
```

I'm trying to understand child better, but I didn't got it yet, if someone could help me. Thank you and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

States are simply ways to attach a view/controller combination to a label(url) in a way that you can have multiple ui-view on a page rather than only one ng-view. How you structure those within your application is up to you, but the url attached to the state is important, as are any query string parameters you might provide.

The first thing to consider is that the parent page's URL will be part of your browser's URL but not necessarily part of your state's url unless you expressly want it to be. So if your "form.profile" state contains the ui-view that you intend to load the "form.movie" state into, the browser will display

/path/to/your/app/#/form.profile/form.movie

The parent/child relationship is expressly encoded in the url and movie will be inserted into the ui-view within profile's template (about.view.html).

Furthermore, say you had multiple movies you wanted to show with your form.movie state. And perhaps you had some navigation that would allow people to choose a movie from a list and load it in the child view. In this case if you had both links using ui-sref="/movie" the first would work but the second would not show a change in the page. Why? Because the state of the page did not change. The url is the same and therefore ui-router thinks no change is necessary. You would instead have to define the state like this:

```
        .state('form.movie', {
            url: '/movie?movieId',
            templateUrl: 'modules/movie/movie.view.html',
            controller: 'MovieController as vm'
        })
```

And then provide some identifying data in the ui-sref to indicate which movie to display. Something like this:

```
<a ui-sref="form.movie({movieId:1})">Movie 1</a>
<a ui-sref="form.movie({movieId:2})">Movie 2</a>
```

These links would render on the page as /path/to/my/page/#/form.movie?movieId=1 (or 2). Or, using the above parent/child relationship for profile and movie it might look like this:

```
/path/to/my/app/#/form.profile/form.movie?movieId=1
```

You can see these URLs when hovering over them in a browser but inspecting the HTML will just show you the ui-sref definition and it can be rather confusing.

Comment: Not actually, I based in this tutorial that works very nice (https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router) and use the '.' notation in the ui-sref, and I also tried your approach and it don't work. Thank You anyway @tokkov

Comment: That tutorial is doing exactly the same thing I described. Perhaps if you included the HTML of your templates and your controller in your question I could provide more help. As it is the tutorial and my answer are essentially the same with the exception that the tutorial uses a dot separator notation and I use a slash separator. Either work and the behavior is identical.  But without the rest of your application I cannot be more specific about why this behavior is occurring for you.

Comment: You edited your answer @tokkov, the first answer you gave don't work, when u said that was based on the URL, ''The ui-sref must point to the url you define in the state, not to the state label..''. Now I have already solved my problem. Tks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
> Here is simple working example of state provider


    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head ng-app="myApp">

                <script src="angular.min.js">
                </script>
                <script src="../../dist/ng-flow-standalone.js">
                </script>
                <script src="angular-ui-router.min.js">
                </script>
                <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                <link href="simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var app=angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']);
                    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
                        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
                        $stateProvider
                            .state('def', {
                                url: '/',
                                templateUrl: 'def.html'//this is static page
                            })
                            .state('upld', {
                                url: '/upld',
                                templateUrl: 'upl.html'//this is static page      
                            })
                            .state('del', {
                                url: '/del',
                                templateUrl: 'del.html' //this is static page     
                            })
                            .state('show', {
                                url: '/show',
                                templateUrl: 'show.html'  //this is static page    
                            });  
                </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a ui-sref=".upld" id="a1">Upload Images</a>
    <a id="a2" ui-sref=".del">Delete Images</a>
    <a id="a3" ui-sref=".show">Show Images</a>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Tks @vishal, but the problem was already solved. The approach on your answer is right, I was already using in it in my fixed navigation as well, it works, my problem was on state views.